# Display C#-array in XAML DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid, itemssource

it should be simple, but I do not find the answer.
I have any datadrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myTabell2"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="294,67,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Height="218"
    Width="137"/>
```

and in code-behind C#

```
myTabell2.ItemsSource = LoadStringData();
```

with

```
    private string[] LoadStringData()
    {
        return "One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight".Split();
    }
```

I found the above example in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/working-with-datagrid-in-silverlight/
there they write the result is a list with the values "one" "two" .......

In my try i do not get the values, but the length of the "values" i.d. "3" (length of one) "3" (length of two) "5" (length of three)

SO my question: what could be wrong in my code? (by the way, yes, I could do it with a class and List or any other list. Nevertheless I would like to understand whats wrong in my code. why not doing it simple, if it ist simple?

Comment: you are getting values as this is default behaviour for the arrays ToString() method, if you will use the List<string> you will get the desired result. BTW have you included the `xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"` in your xaml as that changes the actual grid it self HTH

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your code isn't working is because:
1. Your xaml declarations should have:

```
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
```

2. Your DataGrid Declaration should be like this:

```
<data:DataGrid></data:DataGrid>
```

This is crucial as you will use two different DataGrids which from my point of view are evaluating arrays in different ways. That's why your code produces different results to the one you based it on.
**UPDATE**
As the **System.Windows.Controls** was NOT referenced in the project OP was unable to use the right assembly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still doens't work. I added the xmlns:data. declaration, changed the DataGrid declaration. But my system says: DataGrid ist not found in this namespace. any further idea?

Comment: is your project .NET 4 or later ?

Comment: Windows8, MS VisualStudio 2013

Comment: Right Click your Project, not Solution, select Properties and check the target framework. And Another thing have you added a reference to your project to include Windows.Controls?

Comment: sorry, additional to referencies. In the referencies I see Windows.Base, no Windows.Controls. Where would I find these? I added the Xceed.wpf.toolkit, nothing else

Comment: In your Solution Explorer you can see your Project if it is expanded you can see references->RightClick on it and select add references. When window opens select .NET tab and search for System.Windows.Controls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52322/discussion-between-user3367867-and-xamlmax)

Comment: I stop solving the problem. I tried it in SharpDevelop4.3, too. The same problem. I get the length, not the values. I also tried it with List<string> data = new List<string>();             data.Add("xyz1");
data.Add("zyx2");
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;

Comment: the result is always the same. My environments of sharpdevelop and of MS VS2013 always return length, not values !

Comment: Have you tried doing it this way: `return new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};` see if that works. Or `.Split(' ');`